# Heroku Add-on : How to get customer information who are going to use add-on?

Tags: heroku

I have developed one add-on using REST WCF now client wants to get information of customer who are going to use this add-on, I have researched on google but couldn't find relevant things so 
if any expert on heroku here can explain me about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't disclosure any information about the customers to you. The only information you know about the client is its `heroku_id` that is passed by Heroku during provisioning (see the the [Heroku API spec](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/reference/api-spec)).

```
Action :  POST /heroku/resources
Input  :  json { "heroku_id": "app123@heroku.com", "plan": "basic",
                 "callback_url": "https://api.heroku.com/vendor/apps/123" }
Output :  json { "id": 456, "config": { ... }, "message": "your message here" }
```

Under the terms of the Add-ons License Agreement Heroku can optionally provide you email addresses of your add-on users. You may use this information exclusively for issues related to the operation of your add-on. More details are available in the [operations](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/business/ops) page.

Comment: During provision call of Heroku to my add-on i need to call post method to get heroku id ?? I did't get exactly where i need to put this call , can you please explain me?

Comment: This ID is sent to you by Heroku when Heroku calls your application to provision a new API. Please read the Heroku technical integration section https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/how/overview